# And customer property in AWS dynamodb for cfndsl

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, cfndsl

I would like to defined DynamoDB in AWS like:

```
{
"Type" : "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
"Properties" : {
  "AttributeDefinitions" : [ AttributeDefinition, ... ],
  "GlobalSecondaryIndexes" : [ GlobalSecondaryIndexes, ... ],
  "KeySchema" : [ KeySchema, ... ],
  "LocalSecondaryIndexes" : [ LocalSecondaryIndexes, ... ],
  "ProvisionedThroughput" : ProvisionedThroughput,
  "SSESpecification" : {               ##this is the keypart
      "SSEEnabled": true               ##this is the keypart
    },
  "StreamSpecification" : StreamSpecification,
  "TableName" : String,
  "Tags" : [ Resource Tag, ... ],
  "TimeToLiveSpecification" : TimeToLiveSpecification
}
}
}
```

I want to use Properties to defined SSESpecification

```
DynamoDB_Table(:tableName) do
  ...
  Property (["SSESpecification", {:SSEEnabled => true}])
  ...
End
```

I always get error.

```
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cfndsl-0.16.9/lib/cfndsl/properties.rb:16:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
```

OR I change to:

```
Property ("SSESpecification", {:SSEEnabled => true})
```

and get errors:

```
6: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
Property ("SSESpecification", {:SSEEnabled => true})
                            ^
C:/work/dfsi/infra/cfndsl/nesteddb.rb:85: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
end
^~~
```

Can you give me example correct way defined "SSESpecification" in cfndsl?

Comment: You definitely should show the error message you receive, in case someone else encounters the same response.

Comment: @AlexHarvey I add some errors here